# How to add "..." to the end of product title, php echo

Tags: php, string, html

I'm trying to add `"..."` after my product title.

```
<a href="index.php?section=1&show=<?php echo $row['id_product']; ?>">
<?php
    $title = $row['name'];
    $newtext = str_pad($title,  6, "...");
    echo $newtext; ?>
</a>
```

But php print only the `$row['name']` and doesn't add `"..."`

How is it possible to make this happen?

Comment: Your code works for me. But keep in mind that if $title is 6 or more characters long, there will be no ... on the end.

Comment: It seems like you're unclear about what [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) does. It only adds characters if the input (`$title`) is shorter than the specified length (`6`, in your example). If you want to append `...`, just do `echo $title . '...';`.

Comment: Oh. I want to add ".." to a maximum lengh (limit) of "$row['name'].

Comment: You asked about how to do it with PHP so I'm not posting it as an answer but you might want to use css text-overflow attribute with the ellipsis value to get the 3 dots effect on text that doesn't fits its conainer.

Comment: Like :  Nvidia GTX 1070 '...' < . remember $row['name'] has varchar 70

Comment: Why use str_pad then? Why not just $row['name'] . '...'?

Comment: @CMiller I want to add '...' for design bugs when the text is to long.

Comment: check for the length from the query then and do it in the query, then concatenate as @EdCottrell suggested, set inside a conditonal statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) docs

> If the value of pad_length is negative, less than, or equal to the length of the input string, no padding takes place, and input will be returned.

You can get the length first of your string then just add the length of the string to pad. In your case,

```
$title = $row['name'];
$length = strlen($title) + 6;
$newtext = str_pad($title,  $length, "...");
echo $newtext;
```

For cutting the string to a smaller string, then adding `"..."`. You can use `substr()` then concatenate. With additional check for more than 6 string length

```
$title = $row['name'];
$newtext = strlen($title) > 6 ? substr($title, 0, 6) . "..." : $title;
echo $newtext;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. One more question or error I found. When echo $newtext there is x2 "..." and not one '...' . You know why?

Comment: You can use `$length = strlen($title) + 3;` to set the pad_string to only three characters

Comment: My mistake, this isn't what im looking. I want to cut the text and add '...' This only add ... for all the $title and not cut to a lenght limit. (sorry for my english, im from argentina ;)

Comment: You want to make the string smaller then add `"..."`? E.g. `abcdefghij` should be `abcdef...`. Is that how it is?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. is 6 the maximum length you want for $title?

Comment: Maybe but I just want to cut the title for "design" structure

Comment: Thanks a lot @Erwin +1 . Works perfectly